# Angular service worker refresh on server headers update

Tags: angular, nginx, service-worker, angular7, angular-service-worker

I'm using Angular 7 with the famous `ngws-worker.js`.

I deployed a new release of my project, and see after refresh an error due to a CSP too restrictive. I update it on my server (nginx), but I cannot update the result on client side...

If I disabled the service worker, all is OK, new headers are received.

But it seems that the service-worker didn't see any update on files, so it cannot update server headers... Everytime I re-enabled the service worker, it re-fetch an old version :/

Is there a way to refresh it ?

I don't understand how it works internally I think..

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/988402162312114177) you can disable CSP headers for ngws-worker.js file. Any non safe content can't pass webpage to reach worker.

Comment: Problem still exists ; angular service worker refresh is based on content body hash, so if headers only are updated, the service worker don't see them

Comment: @Doubidou that is different problem. To handle it I would suggest to render build number into your client code during the CI pipeline, so every deploy automatically has new build version and different code hash.